# Using glob in the Selenium extension to PHPUnit to identify elements

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm writing a Selenium test case in PHPUnit using the Selenium extension. In the test, I assert that a certain link is present on the page.

For example, say I want to assert that the following link exists in the page:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">click here to enter stackoverflow</a>
```

In order to assert that the link is present I need to identify it. Usually we identify links using their anchor text: `assertElementPresent("link=click here to enter stackoverflow")`.

I don't want to identify the link using its whole anchor text, but just the sub-string "stackoverflow" which the anchor text contains. I can use glob and the star operator in order to do so: `assertElementPresent("link=glob:*stackoverflow*")`

This works perfectly on selenium IDE, but when coding the equivalent in PHPUnit the assertion fails. Here is the equivalent line of code in PHPUnit:

```
$this->assertTrue(isElementPresent("link=glob:*stackoverflow*"));
```

The above assertion fails because the element `link=glob:*stackoverflow*` is not identified. The element should be identified because there exists a link on the page which its anchor text contains the string "stackoverflow".

My question is more general than the simple example I've given: How can I use glob to identify elements in the Selenium extension to PHPUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use XPath expressions in all of our Selenium test cases, but I wasn't involved in writing them and didn't investigate other options. If you cannot find a way to get `glob` to work, you can always fall back on this:

```
self::assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("//a[contains(.,'stackoverflow')]"));
```